# Exhaust fan light removal

Tags: light-fixture, exhaust-fan

[image]

I'm having trouble removing the glass light fixture on my bathroom Exhaust fan. I've read a few other questions like this, but it does not pull down and does not have actual screws. I've attempted pushing and pulling while turning it, but to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: Clearer picture of the 4 rust-colored bits that look like screws (possibly Torx head, but not enough detail or focus to be sure) from here?

Comment: Yeah, the whole grille needs to be removed to get at the light lens.

Comment: I kind of figured it would end up needing removed. It's possible the screws were corroded, but they're completely bare. I was hoping there'd be another way.

Comment: Destruction and replacement?

Comment: I ended up trying to pry the vent with a hammer. The "screws" ended up pulling down with the vent. They are attached and act kind of like a pin that holds it in place. The vent doesn't come entirely off, but the glass can be taken out to replace the bulb.